# What's the name of this inequality $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{x_k}{x_{k+1}+x_{k+2}}>\dfrac{5}{12}n$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

Does anyone know the name of this inequality?

Let $x_k \ge 0, \, k=1, 2, \cdots, n$ ($n\ge 3$) such that $x_k + x_{k+1} > 0, \, k=1, 2, \cdots, n$ where $x_{n+1} = x_1, \, x_{n+2} = x_2$. Then
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{x_k}{x_{k+1}+x_{k+2}}>\dfrac{5}{12}n.$$

Comment: Something must be wrong or missing. Putting in $n=1$ and $x_1=1$, $x_2=x_3=2$ gives $\frac14>\frac5{12}$, which is false.

Comment: These inequalities are famous. See here: https://olympiads.mccme.ru/lktg/2010/5/5-1en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is called the Shapiro Inequality in general,you can look it up on wiki.

I don't believe that the coefficient $5\over 12$ has a stand-alone name.